# order by 2 columns but keep a relative order in one column R

Tags: r

Maybe I'm phrasing this a bit wrong in the title. The idea is that I have a dataframe that looks like

```
Station  From  To  PassIn  PassOut
Stat1    9     16  213     123
Stat1    16    18  123     14  
Stat3    6     7   884     90 
Stat2    7     9   213     33
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
Station  From  To  PassIn  PassOut
Stat1    6     7   884     90 
Stat2    6     7   213     33
Stat3    6     7  213     123
Stat1    7     9   884     90 
Stat2    7     9   213     33
Stat3    7     9  213     123
Stat1    9     16   884     90 
Stat2    9     16   213     33
Stat3    9     16  213     123
```

The stations cannot be ordered alphabetically, they have different names, and I want to order them based on their location. And the second argument in the sorting function should be the `From` column.

I know of `order()`, but I'm unaware of how I can make use of it given the first argument constraint here.

Comment: Which column has the location that you mentioned? Where are the new rows come from when you just want to order? Where is the 2nd row of your original dataset? Looks like there are many more things you want to do apart from ordering here.

Comment: @AntoniosK The `From` column is time, meaning 6 o clock, it's the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
df$Station <- factor(df$Station, levels = c("Station1","Station2","Station3"))
df$From <- as.numeric(df$From)

df[order(df$From,df$Station),]
```